# tabular, small detail

Tags: tables, tabularx

[image]Could you please kindly help me to break the blue boxes (see picture) to the next line so that the Table is narrower? Than you very much for your help!

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Terminology of the laminates for in-plane (tensile and compressive) and mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness testing. \textcolor{red}{pequeño formateo}}
    \label{table:notation}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
        \toprule
        Laminate    & Stacking sequence &          Purpose         \\ \midrule
        LTHIN\textsubscript{IP} & $[(45\degree/0\degree)/(-45\degree/90\degree)]_{4s}$ & \multirow{3}{*}{In-plane testing} \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
        LV1\textsubscript{IP}   & $[$(45$\degree$/V\textsubscript{1}/0$\degree$)/V\textsubscript{1}/($-$45$\degree$/V\textsubscript{1}/90$\degree$)/V\textsubscript{1}$]$\textsubscript{4s} &                   \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
        LV2\textsubscript{IP}   & $[$(45$\degree$/V\textsubscript{2}/0$\degree$)/V\textsubscript{2}/($-$45$\degree$/V\textsubscript{2}/90$\degree$)/V\textsubscript{2}$]$\textsubscript{4s} &                   \\ \midrule
        LTHIN\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}}  & $[(45\degree/90\degree)/(-45\degree/0\degree)]_{6s}$ & \multirow{3}{*}{Mode-I fracture toughness testing} \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
        LV1\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}}    & $[(45\degree/90\degree)/(-45\degree/0\degree)]_{6s}$/V\textsubscript{1}/$[(45\degree/90\degree)/(-45\degree/0\degree)]_{6s}$ &                   \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
        LV2\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}}    & $[(45\degree/90\degree)/(-45\degree/0\degree)]_{6s}$/V\textsubscript{2}/$[(45\degree/90\degree)/(-45\degree/0\degree)]_{6s}$ &                   \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: use `@{}lp{20mm}l@{}` as column declaration (play with the 20mm). Maybe you'll need to add `\raggedright` at the beginning of the breaking cells afterwards.

Comment: please extend your code snipet to complete small document which produce your table (where is define `\degree`?). one solution is use `tabularx` environment: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l X X @{}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- please always provide mwe (minimimal working example), a small complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}`, with necessary preamble with loaded packages and defined new commands for your problem, body of document and ending with `\end{document}`. with this you will help us to help you (preparing a mwe can serve you at finding solution yourself)
- your problem can be solved with using for the second column the column type which enable to break cells' contents into more line as is `p{<widt>}` or `X` from `tabularx` package
- i try to reconstruct from your code snippet an mwe in which i employ `tabularx` and `siunitx` package. in this i try to remedy your code from errors ( also it is easy to lost in it):

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}             
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}  % <---
  \usepackage{siunitx}                                % <---

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%
  \begin{document}
      \begin{table}[htb]
      \centering
      \caption{Terminology of the laminates for in-plane (tensile and compressive) and mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness testing. \textcolor{red}{pequeño formateo}}
      \label{table:notation}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l 
                              >{\hsize=0.65\hsize}X % <---
                              >{\hsize=0.35\hsize}X % <---
                              @{}}
      \toprule
  Laminate    & Stacking sequence &          Purpose                  \\ \midrule
  LTHIN\textsubscript{IP}
      & [(\SI{45}{\degree}/\SI{0}{\degree})/%
        $(\SI{-45}{\degree}/\SI{90}{\degree})]_{4s}$
          & \multirow{3.5}{=}{In-plane testing}                         \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
  LV1\textsubscript{IP}
      & [(\SI{45}{\degree}/V\textsubscript{1}/\SI{0}{\degree})/%
        V\textsubscript{1}/(\SI{-45}{\degree}/%
        V\textsubscript{1}/\SI{90}{\degree})/%
        V\textsubscript{1}]\textsubscript{4s} &                       \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
  LV2\textsubscript{IP}
      & [(\SI{45}{\degree}/V\textsubscript{2}/\SI{0}{\degree})/%
        V\textsubscript{2}/%
        (\SI{-45}{\degree}/V\textsubscript{2}/9\SI{0}{\degree})/%
        V\textsubscript{2}$]$\textsubscript{4s} &                     \\ \midrule
  LTHIN\textsubscript{$G_{\mathrm{IC}}$}
      & [(\SI{45}{\degree}/\SI{90}{\degree})/%
        $(\SI{-45}{\degree}/\SI{0}{\degree})]_{6s}$
          & \multirow{5}{=}{Mode-I fracture toughness testing}        \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
  LV1\textsubscript{$G_{\mathrm{IC}}$}
      & [(\SI{45}{\degree}/\SI{90}{\degree})/%
        (\SI{-45}{\degree}/\SI{0}{\degree})]$_{6s}$/%
        V\textsubscript{1}/\newline
        [(\SI{45}{\degree}/\SI{90}{\degree})/%
         (\SI{-45}{\degree}/\SI{0}{\degree})]$_{6s}$
        &                 \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
  LV2\textsubscript{$G_{\mathrm{IC}}$}
      & [(\SI{45}{\degree}/9\SI{0}{\degree})/%
         (-\SI{45}{\degree}/\SI{0}{\degree})]$_{6s}$/%
        V\textsubscript{2}/\newline
        [(\SI{45}{\degree}/\SI{0}{\degree})/(-\SI{45}{\degree}/
        \SI{0}{\degree})]$_{6s}$ &                   \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
      \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

Comment: this was extremely helpful! thank you so much!